# How Do I Parallelise my Python Code Using MPI? Runge Kutta - N-Body problem

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi

i'm trying to parallelise my python code using MPI in python and desperately need some help. I literally don't know where to start, i just know which part i need to parallelise to make the code run quicker.

The code is a simulation of N-bodies orbiting the sun, i've used the Runge Kutta approximation to do this, and save the final position and velocity each time to a list, i then take these values to plot the data using matplotlib. My next step is to speed this code up and to split the calculations across multiple cores.

Is there anyone here that can help? Really need a solution and happy to compensate you for your time.
I know i need to use MPI on the `step_size = 3600 step_number = 36*24` section of the code, you can see my attempt on the line above.

I'm thinking that i need to get the code to calculate the position and velocity of each of my planets on one core, and simultaneously perform the same calculation on another core for another planet and so on and so forth.

Then i'd need it to take this data back and 're-combine' it so i can then plot the graph.

If someone can reach out to help me i'd be super grateful

Comment: See my updated response.

Comment: See this very nice introduction: https://youtu.be/36nCgG40DJo

Answer (score 2):

My take on this problem is that you have dependencies between the state of the system a t and the state of the system at t-1. The most you could do is have each core calculate the acceleration and change in position of a single planet or the sun (probably negligible). Each process has to send the state of the planet it is treating to all the other processes and conversely receive the new state of all the other planets and sun from the other processes via MPI. Doing that will gain you nothing as the time spent in communication will probably nullify any gain in parallel calculations.

Using Python multiprocessing will also result in multiple processes and the same impact in terms of communication. Due to the GIL, multithreading is out of question.

That brings you to the choice of using C and OpenMP to share the state and parallelize your code across threads.

The other option is to use Julia which has a similar syntax to Python but provides C like speed except for the slow startup time while JIT compilation occurs.

I might be wrong, and would appreciate being corrected as I would be curious to see an alternative.

[EDIT 02/24/2021]
I understand that this probably an academic project. The way you should approach the problem is as follows:
You should start one process per planet / sun plus an extra process that will be the "controller". The controller will identify itself as rank number of planets/sun + 1. The others will simulate by picking their rank as the index within the array containing the planet states and picking up one planet accordingly. The controller sends the state of the system to each other process and gets back the new state of each planet from each of the processes. The worker processes get the global state and send back their planet state after one time step. The controller can send an exit message to all processes when the desired number of time steps is reached.

See this very nice introduction: https://youtu.be/36nCgG40DJo

Comment: Thanks for the response! So my first thought is that yes, we'd need to basically calculate the new positions of each planet and or moon, as they orbit the sun. Ideally as you say, if i could do this on each core for each planet and then pass that data back to collate it all. Unfortunately i don't have much choice, i have to do this on MPI and or open MPI

Comment: You also have to do it in Python?

Comment: Yeah has to be python

Comment: @M.B Gravity is a long-range force and unless you implement some clever algorithm to split the interaction in short-ranged and long-ranged components that will allow you do optimisations such as Verlet neighbouring lists and mean fields, your best bet is to keep the global state synchronised in all ranks and let each of them compute the interaction between a subset of pairs, then use the mpi4py equivalent of `MPI_Allgather` (`comm.Allgather()`, if I recall correctly) to again obtain the global state. Mind that the parallel version **will run slower** than the sequential one.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [@Tarik's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66339401/8787505), MPI is meant to be used when you have many calculations/processes that can all be done independently of each other, preferably where data is not shared between the processes.
This is often referred to as an "embarrassingly parallel problem".
Reason for this is because communication between MPI processes is slow if it has to be done many times and the processes do not share memory with each other.

In your situation, you need to communicate between all processes for every step.
Unless every step takes a long time to complete (let's say, an hour or so), then the overhead caused by MPI communications is minimal.
However, I think that in your case, every step only takes a few seconds or so at maximum, in which case MPI will simply slow down your code more than it speeds it up.

What you probably need here, is OpenMP, which is specifically made to handle frequent communications between processes and which also shares memory.
Python however, due to how it works, cannot do OpenMP.
So, if this really needs to be sped up using parallelization, you will have to use something like C or Julia with OpenMP.

Another thing to keep in mind is that Python is absolutely **NOT** designed for efficiency, but for accessibility; user-friendliness; and versatility.
In fact, Python is one of the slowest programming languages used in the world, and by far the slowest language of all popular ones (e.g., C, C++, Fortran, Java, Python, Ruby, Javascript, C#, etc.).
Therefore, when doing Python programming, it is a very good idea to also be able to do C programming when efficiency becomes a priority.
Given that Python can interact with C code relatively easily, it is very common for big Python programs to have their performance-heavy operations done in C and providing a Python wrapper/interface to those operations.